# Como carregar módulos concatenados com o Gulp no RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, requirejs

Meu projeto possui vários módulos AMD que estão sendo carregados no browser pelo RequireJS.

No entanto, estou migrando do JavaScript para o TypeScript e também quero utilizar o Gulp para fazer a transpilação para o JavaScript e gerar um arquivo `bundle.js` que conterá todos os módulos já transpilados e concatenados.

Porém, não sei como carregar esse `bundle.js` no browser.

Antes de usar o TypeScript eu fazia assim:

1. Definia um arquivo `boot.js` que explicitava os módulos:

```js
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: '/',
  paths: {
    /* ========================== libs ========================== */
    jquery: '/node-dependencies/jquery/dist/jquery',
    ace: '/node-dependencies/ace-builds/src',
    vis: '/node-dependencies/visjs-network/dist/',
    jsYaml: '/node-dependencies/js-yaml/dist/js-yaml',
    bootstrap: '/node-dependencies/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle',
    fontawesome: '/node-dependencies/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all',
    toastr: '/node-dependencies/toastr/build/toastr.min',
    /* ========================== app ========================== */
    aceEditor: 'app/js/aceEditor',
    btnLoadFile: 'app/js/btnLoadFile',
    btnValidateYaml: 'app/js/btnValidateYaml',
    graphEditor: 'app/js/graphEditor',
    btnBuild: 'app/js/btnBuild',
    btnExecute: 'app/js/btnExecute',
    loadingScreen: 'app/js/loadingScreen',
    Task: 'app/js/Task',
    Digraph: 'app/js/Digraph',
    experiment: 'app/js/experiment',
    app: 'app/js/app',
    yamlParser: 'app/js/yamlParser',
    taskInfo: 'app/js/taskInfo',
    Button: 'app/js/Button'
  }
});

requirejs(['jquery'], function () {
  requirejs(['bootstrap', 'fontawesome'], function () {
    requirejs(['loadingScreen'], function (loadingScreen) {
      loadingScreen.show();
      requirejs([
        'aceEditor',
        'btnLoadFile',
        'graphEditor',
        'btnExecute',
        'btnValidateYaml',
        'btnBuild'], function () {
        requirejs(['app'], () => $(document).ready(loadingScreen.hide));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

2. Carregava o `boot.js` no browser da seguinte forma:

```html
<script src="/node-dependencies/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/app/js/boot.js"></script>
```

---

Minhas dúvidas são:

1. Dado o arquivo `bundle.js` gerado pelo Gulp, como eu faço para que ele seja carregado no browser?
2. Eu ainda preciso explicitar os módulos no `boot.js` sendo que eles já estarão todos dentro do mesmo arquivo?